# how can I find jquery elements that are immediately followed by a error span

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am working with twitter bootstrap and the jquery validate plugin

I have a form row that looks like:

```
<div class="form_row" >
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input01">home phone</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="number" class="span4" class="input-xlarge" id="home_phone" name="home_phone" value="<?php echo $this->property->home_phone ?>" rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your home phone." data-original-title="homephone" >
        <input type="number" class="span4" class="input-xlarge" id="cell_phone" name="cell_phone" value="<?php echo $this->property->cell_phone ?>"  rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your cell_phone." data-original-title="cell_phone" >
      </div>
</div>
```

after validation, when I look at it in firebug, the inputs with errors are followed by span.error. I would like to select these inputs. So far I have:

```
$.filter(function() { return $(this).next("span.error"); })
```

but I'm getting the following error:

TypeError: elems is undefined
[Break On This Error]

return elems.length === 1 ?

Can anyone give me a hand here?

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$("input").filter(function() { return $(this).next("span.error").length == 1; })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('input').filter(function(index) { return typeof($(this).next("span.error")!='undefined'); })
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the `span.error` elements and then work backwards to the `input` elements:

```
​var inputs = $('span.error').prev('input');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cKaka/).

Incidentally, for what it's worth, this approach is (albeit only *marginally*) faster (in Chromium 19) than using the `filter()` approaches. Clearly, it's a micro-optimisation, though. Of course, assuming a browser that supports `document.querySelectorAll()` and `previousElementSibling`, using native DOM methods is even faster. But not, in all honesty, by as much as I would have expected.

References:

- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).